# Getting average value from matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, average

I have a simple plot which feature a lot of data points, when i have have graph. Is there a way that i can simple click on all these point and allow matlab to give me a average value of them?

Thank you

Comment: If you want better answer please provide your data example, how you plot them and average of what you want to calculate.

Comment: My guess is he's trying to do this on a plot.  So no there matlab can't do this on the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if you don't want to do it programmatically would be to use the data brush and statistics.

I used `plot(rand(1,200))` to generate my data.  After it has plotted go to Tools > Data Statistics.  Y-mean is what you are looking for.

[alt text http://www.thinkextensively.com/misc/stackoverflow/images/matlab2.png](http://www.thinkextensively.com/misc/stackoverflow/images/matlab2.png)

To get the mean of a specific set of data, select the data you want, then in the menu go to Tools > Brushing > Create New Variable . . ..  This creates a variable containing the boxed data.  To get the mean do `mean(ans)`.  The second value in the vector is the Y-mean.
[alt text http://www.thinkextensively.com/misc/stackoverflow/images/matlab1.png](http://www.thinkextensively.com/misc/stackoverflow/images/matlab1.png)

Comment: If I recall correctly, you don't even need to brush first.  You can go directly to Tools->Data Statistics and get the stats for the whole plot.

Comment: You are absolutely right...brushing actually has no effect on data statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [data brush](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/brh7_p3-1.html).

Click brush icon on the figure toolbar and make a selection. Then select in menu Tools-Brushing-Create new variable. You can leave default variable name `ans`. This variable will contain X and Y coordinates of all selected points. Then just run `mean(ans(:,2))` to get average of Ys.

Comment: I think you want to say 'brush'.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear average of what values you wanted to calculate. I assume, it's y-coordinates.

I would use RBBOX function to select set of points on the plot.

Try this code:

```
% sample data
data = rand(1,100);
datax = 1:numel(data);

% draw simple plot
plot(data,'.')

% select the points with mouse and get coordinates
k = waitforbuttonpress;
point1 = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');    % button down detected
finalRect = rbbox;                   % return figure units
point2 = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');    % button up detected
point1 = point1(1,1:2);              % extract x and y
point2 = point2(1,1:2);
pmin = min(point1,point2);
pmax = max(point1,point2);

% find the data selected and get average of y values
idx = data >= pmin(2) & data <= pmax(2) & datax >=pmin(1) & datax <= pmax(1);
dataAverage = mean(data(idx));
```

I have to claim large portion of this code is from rbbox documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to plot an average (or at least calculate it) from already plotted data.

With [plotAverage](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27134) from the [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/), you can do it quite easily.

```
%# plot some data
figure
plot(randn(100,5))

%# add the average line at every 5th point
[plotHandles, average] = plotAverage([],5:5:95);

%# and you have a line on the plot, and its handles and data in the workspace.
```