# Select data from a 3d plot

Tags: matlab, select, plot

I have a 3d plot.
I want to select a certain area in the plot and get the points within this area into a variable.
Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "select?" Do you mean with a mouse? Also what do you mean by "within this area?" Does this mean you want all the points within some ball of radius `r` centered at the selection point?

Comment: From what data or function did you make the plot ?

Answer (score 1):

See Jonas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784155/matlab-how-do-i-get-3d-coordiantes-from-a-user-click/2784399#2784399) to a similar question.

You may want to have a look at [select3d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1241-select3d-m-select3dtool-m) from the file exchange. It allows you to select patch objects in 3D ...

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at [data brushing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/brh7_p3-1.html), that has been mentioned e.g. by @yuk in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557164/getting-average-value-from-matlab-plot/2557377#2557377).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [RBB3SELECT](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7191-rbb3select) from File Exchange.